# How do I assign a prototype to an object literal?

Tags: javascript

I've serialized some data using JSON and I have to turn the plain objects back into "classes". I've tried this:

```
function Location() {}

Location.prototype.getX = function() {
    return this.x;
};

var p = {x: 3, y: 5};
p.prototype = new Location();

console.log(p.getX());
```

But I get an error that `getX` is undefined. Is there a way to make this work or will I have to construct a new `Location` and copy the properties from the object manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your browser support needs you may be able to use `Object.create` which is intended for exactly this purpose:

```
function Location() {}

Location.prototype.getX = function() {
    return this.x;
};


var p = Object.create(Location.prototype);
p.x = 3;
p.y = 5;

console.log(p.getX()); // 3
```

I think this also more clearly states your intentions, and other methods such as use of `__proto__` have been deprecated and will likely disappear from browsers in the near future.

Documentation (and polyfill) can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

**EDIT**

Object.create is the best approach as it allows extension of the prototype at runtime and passes the `instanceof` test

```
Location.prototype.print = function() {
    console.log("modifying the prototype at runtime should work");
}

// p gets print method from prototype chain
p.print(); 

// true with Object.create
p instanceof Location;
```

Comment: Your answer is good as well, but it doesn't exactly answer my question. If I were to use `Object.create`, I might as well just use the constructor. I wanted to see if there was a way to avoid assigning the members again.

Comment: The accepted answer *is* assigning the values again. Given your use case I would just have `Location` accept an optional config object, e.g. `new Location(p)`.

Comment: No, I can currently just `JSON.parse` the object and then assign `__proto__` and I'm done.

Comment: `__proto__` is non-standard and deprecated. I'll edit my answer to show why the above is the correct way

Comment: You are right, I'll select your answer as best. In my specific case however I have a controlled environment (Node.JS + V8), so I can use `__proto__` until I get around to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `prototype` object is a property of constructors (functions). In your case you should use `__proto__` instead:

```
function Location() {}

Location.prototype.getX = function() {
    return this.x;
};

var p = {x: 3, y: 5};
p.__proto__ = new Location();

console.log(p.getX()); // 3
```

Take a look at these MDN articles:

- [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)
- [Object.prototype.**proto**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

## **EDIT**

As Bergi stated, `__proto__` is a non-standard feature and therefore MDN recommends using [getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) and [setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) (not supported yet) methods.

Since `setPrototypeOf` is not supported yet, I recommend you copying all properties from `Location` instance to `p` manually:

```
function Location() {}

Location.prototype.getX = function() {
    return this.x;
};

var p = {x: 3, y: 5};
var l = new Location();
for (var k in l) {
    p[k] = l[k];
}

console.log(p.getX());
```

Comment: You should mention that one **should not** use `__proto__` - it's non-standard.

Comment: @Bergi I agree. I'll fix that.

Comment: there's an error in the edited code. should be `p[k] = l[k];`